# How can we transpose rows to columns by Entry ID in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a data which I want to transpose to columns by EntryID, I am very confused on how can I achieve this task in C# using LISTS and FOREACH LOOP.

Sample data:

[image]

Required data format:

[image]

Comment: What is your source data type? A DataTable or a collection?

Comment: It is a Collection

Comment: FYI, this is generally called a "pivot"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is tagged Linq, so that what I would use.

Start by grouping the records by EntryID and then for each group you select the name from the only entry with ColID == 1 , the phone number from the only record with ColID == 2, etc

ie

```
var summary = 
    (from r in records 
    group r by r.EntryID into results
    select new 
    {
        Name  = results.Where(a => a.ColID == 1).Select(a=>a.ColValueText).SingleOrDefault(),
        Phone = results.Where(a => a.ColID == 2).Select(a=>a.ColValueNum ).SingleOrDefault(),
        City  = results.Where(a => a.ColID == 3).Select(a=>a.ColValueText).SingleOrDefault(),
        Email = results.Where(a => a.ColID == 4).Select(a=>a.ColValueText).SingleOrDefault()
    }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: If the City whose ColID == 3 is not present in the database then it is throwing error SEQUENCE CONTAINS NO ELEMENTS ... Can we validate the columns existence in result before putting in SELECT ???

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: More than PERFECT!